# Type checking for localStorage

Tags: typescript

How to make localStorage get/set call typesafe? I tried

```
// global.d.ts
export declare global {  
  interface Storage {
    getItem(key: 'abc'): string | null;
    setItem(key: 'abc', value: string): void;
  }
}
```

and in my code file

```
// code.ts
localStorage.get('xyz'); // no error here
```

But I want ts to complain that only 'abc' is allowed as key. I know I can make a wrapper for localStroage and can strict the params, but I want to extend it globally via d.ts

Comment: In general this code works. However it doesn't *override* but *overload* the method. I don't think there is a way to *override* the types of the functions.

Comment: There is an exemple of what you want to achieve on this [sandbox](https://playcode.io/1460241)